# Arima model not showing seasonality in its forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, box-jenkins

The following is a seasonal(not perfectly) time series sequence that I am trying to fit an ARIMA model to:

[image: data]

I performed box-cox transformation, 1 seasonal differencing and 1 regular differencing to get the data in stationary format(confirmed by adf test). Following are the acf and pacf plots after the transformation:
[image: after_transformation]

Then i used the following model to fit the data(I tried a few other combinations as well, but this one gave the best AIC):

```
model <- Arima(data, order=c(3,1,4), seasonal = list(order=c(3,1,1), period=12),
               lambda = lambda, include.constant = TRUE, method="CSS-ML")
```

The model specs:
Series: data
ARIMA(3,1,4)(3,1,1)[12]
Box Cox transformation: lambda= 0.4061528

Coefficients:
ar1      ar2     ar3      ma1     ma2      ma3     ma4    sar1     sar2     sar3
1.3674  -1.3623  0.8400  -1.4801  1.6890  -1.1270  0.2671  0.0487  -0.0524  -0.1724
s.e.  0.0490   0.0545  0.0474   0.0620  0.0731   0.0707  0.0454  0.0661   0.0554   0.0547
sma1
-0.7865
s.e.   0.0524

sigma^2 = 0.003792:  log likelihood = 706.92
AIC=-1389.84   AICc=-1389.22   BIC=-1338.84

Training set error measures:
ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE    MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set -0.001031931 0.1744619 0.1306821 0.01718023 2.23941 0.1712296 0.04060468

The model residual diagnostics are as follows:

[image]

The residuals seem to be satisfying the requirements of zero mean and Homoscedasticity but not the normality assumption(shapiro test with a p-value of 0.001227).

The forecast however, doesn't seem to replicate any sort of seasonal patterns, it is just a straight line(I used forecast(model, h=150) for this), there are no 10 year fluctuations, as there are in the original data:

[image]

The model fit:
[image: fit]

What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "The forecast however, doesn't seem to replicate any sort of seasonal patterns, it is just a straight line"? Just from the chart that follows, it *isn't* a straight line, and it *does* have (monthly) seasonality. Did you expect it to also fluctuate following the ~10 year cycle you can see in the data?

Comment: @ChrisHaug Yes, that's what I meant, the 10 year cycle fluctuation. Thanks for pointing it out, will edit the question.

Comment: Why would you expect it to follow a 10 year cycle?  You have a 12 month seasonality term, not a 10 year seasonality term.  In effect, you've told it there is no 10 year cycle, so of course it's not going to fit one.

Comment: @jbowman thanks for your reply, it makes sense.. so what changes would you suggest? change the seasonality term(by perhaps aggregating the data and bringing it to the years scale first) and then repeat box jenkins?